# Selecting a parent element from its child with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ABrDe

When I click an 'a' element from 'li', I want it to get 'active' class and an arrow to the right (with the 'span' I wrote to JS part). The 'active' part is OK , but I'm confused with the arrow part. I guess I should select 'li', not 'a'. But I only give the 'active' class to 'a'. How can I select "the 'li' who is the parent of the 'a' which has class 'active'"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery selector:

```
$("a").parent("li").hasClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parent` method.

```
$("#resp-list a").click(function () {
     var _this=$(this);
     var parentItem=_this.parent();

    //do whatever you want with the parent.
});
```

Also you may need to use `append` method to add the span to the li.

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve the parent Object with:

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
```

So in you case, the parent jQuery object will hold with the following DOM:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Test ...</a>
</li>
```

Also it's always a good idea to wrap jQuery around a object just one time in a scope. So when you use a selector multiple times, save it to a variable.

```
var $this = $(this);
var $parent = $this.parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtmxq/1/)

```
 $("#resp-list a").click(function () {
     $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active"); 
     $(this).parent().add('<span class="fr arrow-right"></span>');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your fiddle to behave as you expect.

http://cdpn.io/ABrDe

```
    $("#resp-list > li").on('click', 'a', function () {
        $("#resp-list > li > a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
        $(this).parent().prepend('<span class="fr arrow-right"></span>');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this...

http://jsfiddle.net/qdZxQ/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#resp-list a").click(function () {

```
    $("#resp-list a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    if($(this).hasClass("active")){
        $("#resp-list a span").remove();
        $(this).append('<span class="fr arrow-right"></span>');
    }
 });
```

});

Hope this is what u expect.